# Почему строка из файла properties не равна String ?

Tags: java

Сравниваю строки String и значение из файла properties то же String пользуюсь данной конструкцией

```
String str0                 = prop.getProperty("SERVER_LOCAL_IP");//192.168.3.184
String str1 = "192.168.3.184";

if(str0.equals(str1)) {
                    System.out.println("Значения равны " ); 
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Значения не равны " );
                }
```

Но почему то постоянно выдаёт "Значения не равны " пробовал разные методы помог compareTo, но дальше мне нужно отправить эту строку по сети а на клиенте это метод не работает.

Comment: Перегоните обе строки в массивы байтов и визуально их сравните, чтобы стало понятно чем они отличаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте брейкпоинт и сравните значения. Такое часто встречается, если это первая строчка в файле, там может добавляться спец символ (или еще что). Если это ваш случай - сделайте первую строчку каким-либо описательным комментарием к файлу.